# Extremely confused how to install Babel ES6

Tags: babeljs

I know this might be the wrong place to ask this question but ive been trying so hard to install babel. I just dont understand how this works.

I tried running this: `npm install --save-dev babel-cli` but it doesnt understand that command. I dont even have an installer or anything. I thought maybe there is an exe or something but I was wrong. I went to the plugins page and the same thing.

Can someone please tell me how the installation works? ...that is in baby steps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install npm first, but you probably want to install **[Node.js](https://nodejs.org)** instead, as npm comes with Node.js. Once you have Node.js installed, you can use npm from the command line, which is Terminal (Mac/Linux) or Command Prompt (Windows).

Once you've done that, using the command line go to the folder/directory you want to use Babel in. (I'm assuming you know how to use the command line. If not, you need to learn that first.) Then, run `npm init` and fill in the fields with sensible info (or leave them blank).

Then, a sample installation of babel would be `npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015`. This installs Babel and the stuff necessary to transform ES6 code. You can then use Babel by running `babel foo.js --out-file bar.js --presets es2015`. This will compile ES6 code in the file `foo.js` into ES5 code in `bar.js`. (ES2015 is another name for ES6). More information about using the Babel CLI (command line interface) is available in the **[docs](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/)**.

Comment: I dont understand. I got the json file, installed es2015 presets and when I run babel babel foo.js --out-file bar.js --presets es2015 it doesnt work

Comment: It says I have mistakingly installed the babel package

Comment: Could you try running `npm ls` and tell me what it says?

Comment: I am getting a list of babel related stuff. One of them says:  | +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fsevents@^1.0.0

Comment: babel-cli@6.8.0 is on top then I get loads of other things

Comment: You probably want to run `./node_modules/.bin/babel foo.js ...`, not `babel foo.js ...`

Comment: @loganfsmyth It works for me just doing `babel foo.js ...`

Comment: Then you have that in your `PATH` or you have a copy of Babel installed globally.